# How to run kss package? Script not recognized by node

Tags: node.js, node-modules, package.json, npm-scripts, kss

I want to create a CSS documentation and installed KSS Doc: https://github.com/kneath/kss

But the script (kss --css ../styles/style.css --source styles) doesn't work as written in the doc. I don't use Webpack or any fremework, so only have a package.json file.

Here is how to use KSS: https://github.com/kss-node/kss-node

For example, $ kss --demo doesn't work.
Should i add  script in my package.json file, and if yes, what?
Or do I need Webpack?
I'm using node 10.15.3 and KSS is old too.

The error I get:

```
$ npm run kss --confignode_modules/kss/demo/kss-config.json
npm ERR! missing script: kss
```

I would like to be able to run the script, give the source and destination as explained in the doc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a script to your `package.json` in order to run it:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
         ...
        "kss": "node ./node_modules/kss/index.js" // `node` is required on Windows
    }
    ...
}
```

and then run it like this:

```
npm run kss -- --config node_modules/kss/demo/kss-config.json
```

Not the additional `--` after the script name. It tells `npm` that the following arguments need to be passed to the `kss` command itself and not to the `npm run` command.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't recognized the "." in the path. Sorry in French:
'.' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex▒cutable ou un fichier de commandes.

I tried without and still an error.

Comment: What type of OS do you use? Linux/Windows/Mac?

Comment: I use Windows 10. Same problem using Powershell.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try adding `node` before the file path in the `kss` script

Comment: No error, I get this:


> svn_desktop@1.0.0 kss H:\SVN_Desktop
> node ./node_modules/kss/index.js "--config" "node_modules/kss/demo/kss-config.json" --- Don't know how to check if it worked.

Comment: If no error, then it looks like the command finished successfully and the root cause of your problem is fixed. In order to know what arguments you need to pass to the `kss` script, you have to read the docs and play with it. I don't know `kss` module so I can't help with that. Also I think that asking for concrete commands and arguments is a case for another question to keep each problem separated. The first one is already resolved ;)